# Compilation error comes in query string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, string

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;initial catalog=newmits;trusted_connection=true");
cn.Open();

string q = string.Format("SELECT * from upnotice WHERE notice_type LIKE '{0}%'",t);

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(q,cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);

GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Error comes in these line pls help me

Comment: Where **EXACTLY** does this error occur - and **what exactly** is the error? Please provide the **complete and accurate** error message!

Comment: compilation error occur in these line string q = string.Format("SELECT * from upnotice WHERE notice_type LIKE '{0}%'",t);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string q = "SELECT * from upnotice WHERE notice_type like '%Tender%' OR notice_type like '%RecruitementNotice%'";
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 't' does not exist in the current context

Comment: sir i want to get those data  from my database whose notice_type is Tender & RecruitementNotice               sir again compilation error occur

Comment: thankx sir now it's work sir can you explain why they error come

Comment: you must defint t as string:  ... notice_type LIKE '{0}%'","t");

Comment: Define t.
`string t;`